# Need of an addition test set in cross validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-validation

I understand how cross-validation works. However here
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html i states that

"A test set should still be held out for final evaluation"

How to have an extra test set as far as I have not used the train/test split procedure? I have seen nested cross-validation but I do not think this is the case

Any ideas?

```
from numpy import array
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    # data sample
    data = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
    # prepare cross validation
    kfold = KFold(3, True, 1)
    # enumerate splits
    for train, test in kfold.split(data):
        print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data[train], data[test]))

train: [0.1 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.2 0.3]
train: [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6], test: [0.1 0.5]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5], test: [0.4 0.6]
```

Comment: This post is difficult to understand. Are you asking **how** or **why** "A test set should still be held out for final evaluation"?

Comment: I change a little bit by question. The question is about how?

Comment: Why can you not use for example sklearn's `model_selection.train_test_split()` method?

Comment: Cross validation is not used to overcome the problems of model_selection.train_test_split() method?

Comment: I don't think so? Cross-validation is used to gather more robust performance data about the model during training, for example for hyper-parameter search. A held-out test set is used to report the final model performance in a fair way.